# How to resolve issue with React routing on deployed app

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic React with very few routes that work perfectly fine locally while running `yarn start` but does not work when serving the app either on S3 or using `serve -s build`. Here are my routes:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/error" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/session/new">
          <App />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/success">
          <SuccessPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/error">
          <ErrorPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*">
          <ErrorPage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The issue is when I try to visit `localhost:3001/session?token=<token>`. Locally everything works fine as expected. When I build the app with `npm run build` and serve with `serve -s build` and visit the same url I get this error: `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`. I've searched for references of this error but none seems to deal with this issue particular issue - at least as far as my understanding of React goes. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, check that you're handling the errors correctly. For instance if you're fetching data from an api. If the data is not yet available and you will run into that error. You could do something like `{data && data.map(item => ()...}` or `{data && data.length > 0 && data.map(item => ()...}`. So check your containers.

Comment: Hey Ameiz, thanks for the response. The problem is, the error happens even before any request is made to the API. And I do have a try and catch as well. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve the error?